# Bash writing variable? : command not found

Tags: bash

```
 #!/bin/bash

    VAR019='priusr'
    VAR901='pripasswd'

    echo "CREATE DATABASE ftp;
    GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ftp.* TO '${VAR019}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${VAR901}';
```

This will output

```
   : command not found
    : command not found
    : command not found
    : command not found
```

How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There was a lowercase/uppercase problem with `var019` as well

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a [*here document*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) to reduce complexity of quoting.

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR019='priusr'
VAR901='pripasswd'

cat <<HERE 
CREATE DATABASE ftp;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ftp.* TO '${VAR019}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${VAR901}';
HERE
```

To the skeptics, here is the output:

```
CREATE DATABASE ftp;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ftp.* TO 'priusr'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pripasswd';
```

Comment: Variable replacement will not be done using quotes, use double quotes instead

Comment: Or use a backslash to continue the current statement on the next line.

Comment: @Arnaud/@Blagovest: your comments don't have anything to do with my answer. Please move them to the question?

Comment: why is it I am still getting not found errors, and I know how to write variables... why are they acting like commands rather then variables?
heres wht yours gave me as an output: @sehe

this is what I got:

: not found :
: not found :
cat: CREATE DATABASE ftp;
: No such file or directory 'pripasswdN ftp.* TO 'priusr

Comment: How do you invoke it? My guess you are not actually using bash. Otherwise, copy the script _Literally_ and retest

Comment: found out there is something screwy with my Ubuntu terminal??? i ran my same scripts in centos and they work fine??? both using bash test.sh in terminal. so yeah I am actually using bash, but for some reason yesterday it started acting as if my variables were scripts?

Comment: I expect your bash became symlinked to some other shell, or /etc/profile, /etc/bashrc suddenly contains uexpected commands. Make sure your box is secure (this _could_ be intrusion) and good luck finding the cause. Unfortunately I don't recognize the behaviour enough to be able to _guess_ what `set -o`, `shopt` flags could be involved or what other shell has the behaviour you report

Comment: I am working within a virtual testing environment just because of cases like this... I will just move my scripts out and rebuild the virtual box ;) Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your file is using right [EOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (newline separating).

I had exactly the same problem some time ago and it was caused by newlines being `\r\n` (Windows-style) instead of `\n` (Linux style).

In that case, Linux assumes that `\r` is a name of command and tries invoking it. But `\r` is "invisible" character, that's why the strange-looking error message.

See [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-convert-dos-newlines-cr-lf-unix-text-format/) on how to convert CRLF to LF.

Answer (score 0):

I just cut and pasted what you put in your program. The only issue I had was the lack of a closing *double-quote* quotation mark.

I got the following output:

```
CREATE DATABASE ftp;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ftp.* TO 'priusr'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pripasswd';
```

Which seems to be what you want.

The `:command not found` is strange. For example, here's what I get when I enter nonsense:

```
$ asdas
bash: asdas: command not found.
```

This looks like maybe BASH isn't executing your script, or you ***think*** it's executing your script, but it's really executing another script. Use the `which` command and make sure that your version of the script is being executed.

You can also use the `bash` command itself: `bash myscript.sh`. This way, you're verifying that your script is being executed with the BASH shell, and that it is your script that's being executed and not some other script in your path.

Another possibility is that `/bin/bash` is not where your `bash` executable is actually located. You might want to verify that too. I know I've seen this when running Perl scripts with `#! /usr/bin/perl` on top, and Perl was actually located in `/bin/perl` or `/usr/local/bin/perl`.

Also make sure your [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) is formatted correctly. For example, there is no whitespace before the `#`, and it's the first character on the line. That the `!` is right next to the pound sign. Some processors or shells require one and only one space between the shebang and the name of the command interpretor.