# Shell script errors

Tags: linux, shell

I have this shell script and I keep getting strange errors.  One of them is needing a do.  Another is that config.txt is not found but I have it in the directory with the .sh script.

Here is the error printout:

```
jmgreen@jdev:~/citigetbash$ sh citiget.sh
: not found 2: clear
CITIGET
config.txt: No such file or directory

citiget.sh: 17: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")
```

Here is an LS of the directory:

```
jmgreen@jdev:~/citigetbash$ ls
citiget.sh  config.txt  docs
```

Here is my shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
strTitle="CITIGET"
echo $strTitle
#=====CONFIGURATION=============================================================
strLocalDir="/home/jmgreen/citigetbash/"
intMode=1
intTry=5
#===============================================================================
#
# ===== Read in all the URLs
strDir=$(pwd)
URLS=$(cat $strLocalDir"config.txt")
echo $URLS
# ===== Get the file 
if [ $intMode = 1 ]; then
    for u in $URLS;
        do 
            # ===== Get the datestamp ready
            ts=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S);
            echo "Trying..."$u
            wget $u --no-check-certificate -t$intTry -a logfile.txt -O $strLocalDir"downloaded/"$ts".csv";
    done
else
    for u in $URLS;
        do 
            # ===== Get the datestamp ready
            ts=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S);
            wget $u -q --no-check-certificate -t$intTry -a logfile.txt -O $strLocalDir"downloaded/"$ts".csv";
    done
fi
# ===== Clear Screen?
if [ $intMode = 1 ]; then
    clear
fi
echo "===== DONE ====="
exit
```

Comment: Looks very much like DOS newlines.

Comment: Thanks. There must have been some hidden DOS newlines in my file.  a SED removed them all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash writing variable? : command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444953/bash-writing-variable-command-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, replace `cat $strLocalDir"config.txt"` by `cat "${strLocalDir}config.txt"`.

Then, check what does config.txt contains ? This will be moved to the $URLS variable, maybe it s not well formed.

When you have such problems try to insert debug statements, like print. Test the value of your variables each time they're needed, you'll know more precisely where does the code fail.

Comment: Thanks so much.  This helped as well as removing the DOS newlines with a SED command.